# Ajax XHR sometimes comes back as null / undefined? I can't replicate

Tags: javascript, ajax

AJAX CALL

```
var payload = { "strUSERID": parent.objScormManager.getValue("cmi.core.student_id"), "strSESSIONID": parent.objScormManager.getValue("session_id"), "strSCORM_VARNAME": varname, "strSCORM_VARVALUE": varvalue, "strACCUMULATEDTIME": parent.objTimerManager.getTime().toString() };

            try {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/folder/XXXXXXXXX",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ SCORM: payload }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: OnSuccess_Try1,
                    error: OnError_Try1,
                    async: true
                });      

                function OnError_Try1(xhr, status, error) {
//Some of our users are somehow ending up here in the ERROR function instead of the success function. 
//The code below basically tries to check if XHR is undefined, and we are trying to get the ERROR message 
//about why it failed
                    try
                    {
                        return_value = "false";
                        var strError = "";

                        try
                        {
                            var objReturnData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                            strError = objReturnData.Message;
                        } catch (Exception)
                        {
                            if (xhr.responseJSON.Message != null)
                            {
                                strError = xhr.responseJSON.Message;
                            }
                            else if (xhr.responseText != null)
                            {
                                strError = xhr.responseText;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                strError = "XHR response is undefined";
                            }
                        }

                        strMessage = "Varname: " + varname + " Varvalue: " + varvalue + " Error Reason: " + strError;
                        parent.objErrorManager.throwError(strMessage, "579", false)                        
                    }
                    catch (objException)
                    {
//For some reason our users end up in this catch block because 'Unable to get property 'Message' of 
//undefined or null reference'
                        return_value = "false";
                        var strMessage = objException.message;
                        if (strMessage == null) {
                            strMessage = "Generic Client Error SetValue";
                        }
                        strMessage = "Varname: " + varname + " Varvalue: " + varvalue + " " + strMessage;
                        parent.objErrorManager.throwError(strMessage, "580", false);
                    }
                }
```

WEB METHOD

```
public string xxxxx(objScorm SCORM)
{
  //Do stuff here.
}


    public class objScorm
    {
        public string strUSERID { get; set; }
        public string strSESSIONID { get; set; }
        public string strSCORM_VARNAME { get; set; }
        public string strSCORM_VARVALUE { get; set; }
        public string strMASTERY_SCORE { get; set; }
        public string strACCUMULATEDTIME { get; set; }
        public string strLEARNINGOBJECTID { get; set; }
        public string strCOMPLETED { get; set; }
        public string strMASTERYSCORE { get; set; }
    }
```

Basically all of our testing that we have done, even on our live site, the AJAX call always correctly connects to the webmethod and we have no issues, and sometimes we will force an error, and when we DO force an error, the OnError_Try1 function calls and we can clearly see the error that the web method returns using XHR.responseText.

SOMETIMES our users are throwing errors, and xhr.responseText is completely null, so parsing it fails, and likewise xhr.responseJSON is completely null / undefined, causing it too fail.

This obscures the real reason that the webmethod is failing and we don't even know how users are getting to the OnError_Try block because we can't replicate it.

Because 99 out of 100 calls are perfect, but for some reason 1 call will not work, and its not like we are even passing weird data... Usually its just simple strings.

---

Here are some example errors that we get from the CATCH block, BECAUSE xhr is undefined and even trying to check it seems to fail:

**1)    Varname: cmi.core.score.min Varvalue: 0 Unable to get property 'Message' of undefined or null reference**

**2)    Varname: cmi.core.session_time Varvalue: 0006:12:18.96 undefined is not an object (evaluating 'xhr.responseJSON.Message')**

**3) Varname: cmi.core.exit Varvalue: suspend undefined is not an object (evaluating 'xhr.responseJSON.Message')**

**TLDR:** They are hitting the catch block at the bottom of the OnError_Try1 function, because we are trying to parse / access XHR data that DOESN'T come back!!! What gives?

Comment: I want to know why the web method is failing, but XHR (in the super specific scenarios where it is failing which we don't know how to replicate) seems to always be undefined / null and we hit the catch block which provides nothing helpful :/

Comment: You can try to add (at least temporarily) Bugsnag or Sentry so you can get the stacktrace or perhaps even the network log when error occurs.

Comment: The issue is that we have no idea how to duplicate it :/ when we purposefully throw the AJAX error then we always get XHR information back in the OnError_Try1

Comment: The purpose of Bugsnag/Sentry/SessionStack and alikes is to gather information on the client side - so when your customers face these issues the error will be collected and send to your account on the above mentioned platforms. You can try temporarily remove the try/catch block so the raw error(s) can be collected and not masked in the `catch` block. The idea is - since you can not reproduce the error then at least try to get as much information from the live code at action as possible.

Comment: @IVOGELOV Thank you, IVO. How would I get the raw errors? That's what I was trying to do with xhr.responseText but it isn't defined.

Do I just use the "error" in xhr, status, error variables? Is it really that easy? I'm worried it will just come back as "error: Error"

Do you think its possible our users are timing out on the function calls and thats why the issue is happening?

Comment: It is easy but not `that easy` :) You can either use the `webRequest` API as explained on MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Intercept_HTTP_requests) or try to monkey-patch XMLHttpRequest as explained in https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash/issues/309#issuecomment-144124121